# How can you make a field in TFS readonly once a value is set?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

With TFS, I want to make a field be editable only if it's not set yet (or put another way, once a user sets a date, I want the field to be readonly).

I created a custom DateTime and set a rule to make it readonly when value is "". However,

```
<FIELD name="XComplete" refname="Feature.XComplete" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension">
  <WHENNOT field="Feature.XComplete" value="">
    <READONLY />
  </WHENNOT>
</FIELD>
```

However, when I try to set the date on a blank field, it gives this error: "The value for field 'X Complete' must be the same as the original value."

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: You can't make fields write-once. What goal are you trying to accomplish by having write-once fields?

Comment: The goal is to have a form that a user can open and then commit to dates for certain tasks. We want a user to be able to set the initial date but then not modify that date after set/committed.

Comment: What happens when the date slips, which is a guarantee in software development? Use iterations for scheduling work.

Comment: If a date slips, we want to discuss it in a sync meeting and push it there

Comment: ...and how would you change the date to the new due date if the field is write-once?

Comment: This rule wouldn't apply to whoever is running the meeting/sync

Comment: Your questions doesn't say you only want specific users to be able to edit the date, can you adjust the question accordingly please? Also, are you using on-premise? CMMI or Agile project template?